# How to delete folder from sd card while uninstalling the app?

Tags: android, file, uninstallation

I want to find out when my application is unistall and want to delete its related files from sd card:
saved in `getExternalStorageDIRECTORY()/MYNAME/FILES`

i cant save it in data/data/folder path.

please suggest is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `getExternalFilesDir`, android will take care of the clean up at uninstallation time. The min api level required is `8`

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to receive the app-unistallization state using BroadCastReceiver.. The Receiver part will call inside the onReceive you can deleted the folder.